# How to avoid includeing OUTPUT INSERTED when adding a new record to database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, activerecord

I am using the ActiveRecord gem in a Ruby on Rails application. I execute this command to save a new record to my database:

```
Attachment.craete({IdAttachment: id , Name: name, Size: params[:file].size, UploadDate: DateTime.now })
```

Since my table contains a trigger, I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (TinyTds::Error: The target table
> 'Attachment' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if
> the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.):

Checking the auto generated sql query by activerecord, the query contains 'OUTPUT INSERTED' which is the cause of the issue. Is there any way we can avoid including 'OUTPUT INSERTED' into the query?

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [Attachment] 
([IdAttachment], [Title], [IdVch], [IdForm], [Name], [Size], [UploadDate], [IdUser])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[IdAttachment] 
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)', 
N'@0 int, @1 nvarchar(max), @2 int, @3 int, @4 nvarchar(max), @5 float, @6 datetime, @7 int', @0 = 21007, @1 = NULL, @2 = NULL, @3 = NULL, @4 = N'uf21007_pic.jpg', @5 = 87041.0, @6 = '11-20-2022 13:23:20.706', @7 = NULL
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [Identity Inserts with Triggers](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#identity-inserts-with-triggers) yet?

Answer (score 0):

from https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#identity-inserts-with-triggers:

```
  adapter = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter

    # Will assume `bigint` as the id key temp table type.
    adapter.exclude_output_inserted_table_names['my_table_name'] = true
    
    # Explicitly set the data type for the temporary key table.
    adapter.exclude_output_inserted_table_names['my_uuid_table_name'] = 'uniqueidentifier'
```

Comment: This appears to be a verbatim copy of [the documentation](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter#identity-inserts-with-triggers). Which, to your credit, is a good thing to do (so that if that goes away at some point, the answer here doesn't lose its value). But citing your sources is a good idea so that people don't think you're trying to take credit for others' work.